# Is the following a metric on the product space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and suppose we define the following function $d':X^2\times X^2\to\mathbb R^+$ by $d'((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=(d(x_1,y_1)^p+d(x_2,y_2)^p)^{1/p}$ where $0<p<1$. Is $d'$ a metric on $X^2$?

I am having trouble with the triangle inequality. I cannot expand using Minkowski as $0<p<1$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's probably because it doesn't hold. :)

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and let $p=1/2$. Now take

$$P_1=(0,0)$$
$$P_2=(0,1)$$
$$P_3=(1,0)$$

and calculate

$$d'(P_1, P_2)=\big(\sqrt{|0-0|}+\sqrt{|0-1|}\big)^2=1$$
$$d'(P_1, P_3)=\big(\sqrt{|0-0|}+\sqrt{|1-0|}\big)^2=1$$
$$d'(P_2, P_3)=\big(\sqrt{|0-1|}+\sqrt{|1-0|}\big)^2=4$$

Comment: Thanks. Is the statement true for $p>1$?

Comment: @LandonCarter I think yes. Due to Minkowski.